# Install php Imap on mac os sierra and MAMP

Tags: php, imap, mamp

Im trying to edit a web app on my local host and I am getting the following error: `Call to undefined function imap_open()`

I believe this is because I may not have imap installed or activated on my localhost.  I am currently running Mac OS Sierra and MAMP (not MAMP Pro)

I find some things online for older versions of Mac OS or using Brew but I don't use brew, is this necessary to get imap working on my setup?  Can someone help me so I don't run into these imap issues?

Comment: @shaggy The accepted answer on that suggest editing your php.ini on XAMP on Windows 7, I am using MAMP on Mac OSX - furthermore, I looked at the php.ini file and this line: `extension=imap.so` is not commented out; I don't think these are asking the same things as one is trying to debug the error and I just need to know how to get imap working with MAMP on my OS.  I used the error as a reference point but could easily show another imap error if it helps

Comment: it doesn't matter, if you are using Windows or Mac. php.ini is same on both systems. You didn't mention the part about `extentsion=imap.so` in your question, so I've pointed you to solution that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I also had extension=imap.so set in the PHP.ini file, but IMAP still wasn't supported. I finally found what worked for me and hopefully will for your situation as well.

The next thing to make sure of is that extension_dir is correctly set in the same PHP.ini file. Mine was set to MAMP_extension_dir_MAMP. I didn't see where this variable was set. I replaced it with "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/" and now when I look up phpinfo() page I see that IMAP is enabled.

replace php5.3.29 with your php version and no-debug-non-zts-20090626 with whatever folder name you see in the extensions folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but this might help someone.

use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to checkout if the [following files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yylWR.png)
 point to the same path. Also the php.ini has the line of `extension=imap.so` uncommented. And finally, in the `Additional .ini fields parsed` you should see the IMAP location, if there is nothing there, it means that php isn't loading the IMAP.

In my case I run this in the terminal to fix it:

```
brew tap kabel/php-ext
brew install php-imap
brew install php@7.1-imap
```